# Why is $\left ( \frac{x}{j}+1 \right )^{-1}\left ( \frac{1}{j}+1 \right )^{x}=1+\frac{x(x-1)}{2j^2}+O(j^{-3})$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

On this [page](https://books.google.de/books?id=kGshpCa3eYwC&lpg=PP1&hl=da&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q&f=false), it says
$$ \left ( \frac{x}{j}+1 \right )^{-1}\left ( \frac{1}{j}+1 \right )^{x}=1+\frac{x(x-1)}{2j^2}+O(j^{-3}). $$
Could anyone please enlighten me how it is deduced? I tried to find an approximation of $j\mapsto \left ( \frac{1}{j}+1 \right )^{x}$, and then multiplying it by $\left ( \frac{x}{j}+1 \right )^{-1}$. But there is no way I could find a such approximation.

Comment: It's the binomial theorem with exponent x.

Comment: And exponent $-1$.

Comment: Alternatively, substitute $u=\frac1j$ and Taylor expand the function $u\mapsto \frac{(u+1)^x}{ux+1}$ around 0 which gives you the same result.

Comment: @SvenPistre I checked it myself, and it worked. Nice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already said, this is the binomial theorem.

You can also do it with Taylor series. Consider first $$A=\left ( \frac{1}{j}+1 \right )^{x}$$ $$\log(A)=x\, \log\left( \frac{1}{j}+1 \right)=x\left(\frac{1}{j}-\frac{1}{2 j^2}+\frac{1}{3 j^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^4}\right)\right)$$ $$A=e^{\log(A)}=1+\frac{x}{j}+\frac{x(x-1)}{2 j^2}+\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{6
   j^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^4}\right)$$ $$B=\left ( \frac{x}{j}+1 \right )^{-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{x}{j}+1}=1-\frac{x}{j}+\frac{x^2}{j^2}-\frac{x^3}{j^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^4}\right)$$ All of the above makes $$\left ( \frac{x}{j}+1 \right )^{-1}\left ( \frac{1}{j}+1 \right )^{x}=A \times B=1+\frac{x(x-1) }{2 j^2}-\frac{(x+1)x(x-1)}{3 j^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{j^4}\right)$$